# combine text file column wise with different number of lines

Tags: awk, paste

I am hoping that somebody can help me out. 
Hopefully I can finish this task with "paste" or "awk" command with some options (or other simple command).

I have many files with different number of lines. 
I would like to combine these files column wise, but not succeeded as I like. Problem is below.

```
F1.txt 

1   549 15981
2   835 19591
3   322 3896
4   298 3778

F2.txt 

1   549 15981
2   835 19591
3   322 3896
4   298 3778
5   16  202
```

The outfile what I want is

```
1   549 15981   1   549 15981
2   835 19591   2   835 19591
3   322 3896    3   322 3896
4   298 3778    4   298 3778
                5   16  202
```

But I get with my command "paste F1.txt F2.txt | column -s $'\t' -tn" is

```
1  549  15981  1    549  15981
2  835  19591  2    835  19591
3  322  3896   3    322  3896
4  298  3778   4    298  3778
   5    16     202
```

As you see, since F1 dose not have fifth line, fifth line of F2 is shifted to right. This is not what I want. Hopefully somebody can help this issue.

Comment: can't reproduce, work's fine (with needed alignment)

Comment: Your input files need to be tab-separated, not blanks-separated.

Comment: Ed, Thank you very much. Your solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

***Input***

```
$ cat f1
1   549 15981
2   835 19591
3   322 3896
4   298 3778

$ cat f2
1   549 15981
2   835 19591
3   322 3896
4   298 3778
5   16  202
```

***Output***

Using <kbd>`awk`</kbd>, but it will use `array` so may be run into memory issue if your file is too big

```
$ awk -v OFS="\t" 'FNR==NR{a[FNR]=$0;m=m>length?m:length;next}{print (FNR in a)?a[FNR]:sprintf("%*s",length,""),$0}' f1 f2
1   549 15981   1   549 15981
2   835 19591   2   835 19591
3   322 3896    3   322 3896
4   298 3778    4   298 3778
                5   16  202
```

***Explanation***

```
awk -v OFS="\t" '
                 FNR==NR{
                            a[FNR]=$0;                 # save each record of file f1 in array a
                            m=m>length?m:length;       # find max length of line/row from file f1
                            next                       # go to next line
                 }
                                                       # read file f2
                 {
                    # if value exists in array a for row index then 
                    # print array element, else sprintf  with the length of max length line
                    # and current line/row/record of file f2

                    print (FNR in a)?a[FNR]:sprintf("%*s",length,""),$0

                 }' f1 f2
```

Here is one way using <kbd>`pr`</kbd>

```
$ pr -mt f1 f2  
1   549 15981               1   549 15981
2   835 19591               2   835 19591
3   322 3896                3   322 3896
4   298 3778                4   298 3778
                            5   16  202
```

Try sed or some other utility to suppress excess tab, something like below

```
$ pr -mt f1 f2  | sed -E 's/[\t]{3}/\t/g'
1   549 15981       1   549 15981
2   835 19591       2   835 19591
3   322 3896        3   322 3896
4   298 3778        4   298 3778
                    5   16  202
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code:

```
paste F* | awk '($0~/^\t/){$0="\t" $0}{print}'
```

Comment: you can simplify `paste f1 f2 | awk '/^\t/{$0="\t" $0}1'`